# Is it possible to have an input path for variables in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I know the title might be misleading but here my question: In Thymeleaf we set  request params with the input (in HTML). Is it possible to have an input field that sets the path variable. For example I have an method like this:

```
@PostMapping("/house/{id}/rent")
    public String rentHouse(@RequestParam Date startDate, @PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
        House h = new House();
        h.setId(id);
        r.setStartDate(startDate);
        Rents rents = rentsService.createNewRent(h, id);

        model.addAttribute("rent", rents);
        return "House";
    }
```

And in House.html I want something like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/house/${id}/rent/}" method="post">
    <label for="startDate">start Date:</label><br>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="startDate" th:name="startDate" placeholder="startDate"><br>
  <label for="id">house id:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="id" th:name="id" placeholder="id"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

So that when I input something then the result url should be looking like this (I know start Date has false format):
localhost:8080/House/12/rents?startDate=02.21.22

And is it also possible to pass request body in Thymeleaf, I searched for similar questions but they all solved it by manually putting the path variable in the url.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need javascript for that, intercept the form submit and handle the submit with JavaScript. But why aren't you just using an `@ModelAttribute` if you do `/house/rent` remove `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` annotated arguments and replace with `@ModelAttribute House house` Spirng will bind the form elements to the `House` object, which you can then use in your method.

Comment: So a solution  with only  Thymeleaf and HTML is not possible?

Comment: Not without JavaScript.

Comment: Oh I didn't read your edited comment with your method I can also pass the id in the input or not?

Comment: Why not, it is just an input field which you can bind to the `House` object directly.

Comment: ok thx I will try to implement that

Comment: Two things to consider: 1) Why should the user enter an (internal database) ID directly like this? A user should have no contact to implementation details like that. 2) This is an URL for a form post, not a REST URL. It makes no sense to have the ID in the URL like that. All forms should post their data in the request body.